# ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, ora-29913

I am creating external table using hr schema but i get errors

> "ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout ORA-29400:
>   data cartridge error KUP-00554: error encountered while parsing access
>   parameters KUP-01005: syntax error: found "missing": expecting one of:
>   "column, (" KUP-01007: at line 4 column 3
>   29913. 00000 -  "error in executing %s callout"
>   *Cause:    The execution of the specified callout caused an error.
>   *Action:   Examine the error messages take appropriate action."

----------------My Code-------------------

```
create directory ex_tab as 'C:\My Works\External Table';


create table strecords (
st_id number(4),
st_name varchar(10),
schl_name varchar(5),
st_city varchar(15),
st_year number(4)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(TYPE oracle_loader
 DEFAULT DIRECTORY ex_tab
 ACCESS PARAMETERS
 (
  RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
  MISSING FIELDS VALUES ARE NULL
  (
    st_id number(4),
    st_name char(10),
    schl_name char(5),
    st_city char(15),
    st_year number(4)
  )
 )
 LOCATION ('strecords.txt')
);

desc strecords;

select * from strecords;
```

**This is my code, please check it and review it.**

Answer (score 3):

You have several issues here. The immediate one causing your problem is that [you have the clauses in the wrong order](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle_loader-access-driver.html#GUID-B3C6199C-C28C-4FA7-893E-E48C6FB98F52), but you also have `MISSING FIELDS` instead of `MISSING FIELD`:

```
...
 ACCESS PARAMETERS
 (
  RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
  REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
  (
...
```

Then your [field list contents](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle_loader-access-driver.html#GUID-5CAF68BD-5C79-4473-AAA3-AB7CDA00B434) have invalid [data types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle_loader-access-driver.html#GUID-035311F3-58DE-4B7A-81E5-ACE31076290E) for that part of the statement; you can just omit that entirely in this case as those match the table column definition.

> If no field list is specified, then the fields in the data file are assumed to be in the same order as the fields in the external table.

So you can simplify it to:

```
create table strecords (
st_id number(4),
st_name varchar(10),
schl_name varchar(5),
st_city varchar(15),
st_year number(4)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(TYPE oracle_loader
 DEFAULT DIRECTORY ex_tab
 ACCESS PARAMETERS
 (
  RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
  REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
 )
 LOCATION ('strecords.txt')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some operations needed against an Oracle Bug called

***Select From External Table Returns Errors ORA-29913 ORA-29400 KUP-554 KUP-1005 (Doc ID 302672.1)***

When creating an external table, the access parameters should be specified in the following order:

- Comments
- Record Format Info
- Field definitions

Specify Comments, Record Format Info and Field definitions in the correct order. Even inside the Record format Info, 'Records delimited by ...' clause should come before any other clause.

For more information, refer to [the access_parameters clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_params.htm#i1012589).

Comment: The OP isn't getting a KUP-00552 error, so why is that bug relevant? There isn't anything suggesting a permission error either (yet).

Comment: @AlexPoole please look the text of Question again whether `KUP-00552 error..` exists...

Comment: OK. I see 554, 1005 and 1007, but not 552. Where are you seeing that?

Comment: @AlexPoole Excuse me, you're right not 552 but 554. I was confused( because, I could create that table ), thank you.

Comment: No worries, I was confused too *8-)